# Tweet Me Button - JavaScript Button

Tags: javascript, twitter

I an trying to add the Tweet Me button (http://twitter.com/goodies/tweetbutton) from Twitter to my site.  However whenever the button is pressed I get this JavaScript error:

```
A("a.ab-reloading").livequery is not a function
```

Anyone know how I could fix this/

Comment: I can't see where you are getting that from. Could you provide a link to the site, or failing that the chunk of code you are using.

Comment: You can see it on this page:
http://twistedtime.com/testing

Once the 'tweet' button is clicked a pop up appears but the error gets reported on the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you copy and pasted the code from the box, it's best to ping Twitter on this (you can probably tweet @ them with a link to this post).

The code it's referring to is theirs, and it's probably not your fault - nothing much you can do about it (lest you want to edit their source and host it yourself).